# Adding two sides of an array

Tags: c++, optimization, performance, algorithm

The purpose of the program is to add 2 sides of an array starting from the bottom and top of both ends and to find the lowest difference at equal decrements of iteration. The program functions but it's slow.

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    int n = A.size();
    int i, j, rsum, lsum, difference;
    int currentmindifference = 1000;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        lsum = 0;
        rsum = 0;
        for(j = 0; j <= i; j++) lsum += A[j];
        for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++) rsum += A[j];
        difference = abs (lsum - rsum);
        if (difference < currentmindifference) currentmindifference = difference;
    }

    return currentmindifference;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code is \$O(n^2)\$. You can improve it to \$O(n)\$ by precomputing a sum array.

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    int n = A.size();
    int i, j, rsum, lsum, difference;
    int currentmindifference = 1000;

    std::vector<int> pre(n);
    pre[0] = A[0];
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        pre[i] = pre[i - 1] + A[i];

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        lsum = pre[i];
        rsum = pre[A.size() - 1] - lsum;
        difference = abs (lsum - rsum);
        if (difference < currentmindifference) currentmindifference = difference;
    }

    return currentmindifference;
}
```

**Reasoning.** By calculating a sum array, we save the need to calculate `lsum` on each iteration. Furthermore, we notice that we can find `rsum` by finding the total sum less `lsum`.

We can simplify this further by noting that `lsum` and `rsum` are now superfluous. We will also replace `1000` with `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` to ensure we get a true minimum instead of capping it, and check if `A` is empty before using it.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

int solution(std::vector<int> &A) {
    if (A.empty())
        return -1; // or some other meaningful error value

    int n = A.size();
    int minDifference = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

    std::vector<int> pre(n);
    pre[0] = A[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        pre[i] = pre[i - 1] + A[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        minDifference = std::min(minDifference, std::abs(2 * pre[i] - pre[n - 1]));

    return minDifference;
}
```

Further reading: [Prefix sum array and difference array](http://wcipeg.com/wiki/Prefix_sum_array_and_difference_array). <sub><sup>Disclosure: I am an administrator on this site. Excuse the formatting.</sup></sub>

Comment: A word of warning: This code will crash if `A` is empty.

Comment: @Jamal TIL inline LaTeX on SE. Thanks. I tried `$` to no avail, and `$$` only got me display mode.

Comment: @Schism: I guess this isn't mentioned for CR specifically, but yeah, `\$` is our MathJax delimiter.

Comment: This is an improvement, but there's a better algorithm.  See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your baseline code is a good starting point because it (mostly) works, but there are some things that could be improved.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  I don't know that you've actually done that, (you might have used the slightly more enlightened `using std::vector;`) but it's an alarmingly common thing for new C++ programmers to do.

### Avoid arbitrary "magic numbers"

The number `1000` in your code is somewhat suspect.  Where did it come from? Why 1000 instead of 10000 or -9?  It's better to declare some named `const`, or even better, use an already existing constant such as `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

### Use `const` wherever you can

You could (and should) use `const` for the vector that you're passing to your routine, and you can also use it for `n` because it is only initialized once and never changed.

### Consider generality where practical

The code currently only accepts a `std::vector` of `int` values and would require changes if it were used with, for example a `std::vector` of `float` values.  Because this is a mechanism that would be appropriate for many different kinds of numeric values, consider using a templated class instead.

### Consider your algorithm carefully

Other answers have provided alternate ways of doing the calculation, but require more memory.  There is another way of doing this which is fairly simple.  Consider your original code in which you have an `lsum` and `rsum` value at some arbitary point in the vector.  If we consider the values \$l\$ and \$r\$ to be the `lsum` and `rsum` values and \$d\$ to be the value `difference` (without the absolute value), then advancing to the next array value \$i\$ and calculating \$l'\$ and \$r'\$ and \$d'\$ can be done like this:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
d &=& r - l \\
r' &=& r - i \\
l' &=& l + i \\
d' &=& r' - l' \\
&=& (r - i) - (l + i) \\
&=& r - i - l - i \\
&=& r - l - 2i \\
&=& d - 2i 
\end{eqnarray}$$

This result means that there is no need to store the `lsum` and `rsum` values, nor is there a need to create an additional vector of partial sums.

### Try to use descriptive names

I didn't find much use in the name `solution` for the function.  It may be accurate but it doesn't convey much meaning to other programmers.  Consider that it's a minimum partial sum so maybe a better name would be `minpsum`?  I'm not sure that's a huge improvement, but maybe you can come up with something better.  Also `A` is arguably not a great name, but if we consider it to be short for `Array` than it's at least defendable.

## Result

So we can effectively apply all of these ideas into a routine like this:

```
  template <typename T>
  T minpsum(const std::vector<T> &A) {
    if (A.empty()) {return std::numeric_limits<T>::max();}
    T posdiff{std::accumulate(A.cbegin(), A.cend(), T(0))};
    const T zero{0};
    T diff=posdiff;
    T negdiff{-posdiff};
    if (posdiff < zero)
      std::swap(negdiff, posdiff);
    for (const auto &i : A) {
      diff -= (i+i);
      if (diff < zero && diff > negdiff) {
        negdiff = diff;
      } else if (diff > zero && diff < posdiff) {
        posdiff = diff;
      }
    }
    negdiff = -negdiff;
    return posdiff < negdiff ? posdiff : negdiff;
  }
```

As you can see, there is no longer a call to `abs` because that would assume `int` arguments and I wanted to make the code generic, accepting `float` or `double` or whatever as a templated function.  I have also used the C++11 range operator and `std::accumulate` with `const` iterators.  We can try it out with the following driver code:

```
  int main()
  {
    std::vector<int> vec(1000);
    std::iota(vec.begin(), vec.end(), -200);
    int s = minpsum(vec);
    std::cout << s << '\n';
    assert(s == 394);
  }
```

This version of the code will work with the fundamental math types but not with something like `std::complex<std::double>` because the latter type does not implement the comparison operators `<` and `>` which are required by this code.

### Limitations

It should be noted that there is a chance of overflow or numeric wraparound when this code is used.  The assumption made in the code is that the type `T` is sufficient to not only hold each member of the array, but also the sum of all of them, which may or may not be valid.

Also, because of the subtraction, there is the potential for unsigned numbers to "wrap" around 0.  That is, \$3 - 5 = -2\$, but \$-2\$ is not representable as an unsigned number. *Caveat lector.*

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer : This part of the review does not review performances related issues.*

Before anything, I'm assuming you are actually using `std::vector` and used `using namespace std;`. [Using `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is usually considered a bad practice.

You can easily make your code cleaner by defining the local variables in the smallest possible scope. This can be done very easily :

```
int solution(std::vector<int> &A) {
    int n = A.size();
    int currentmindifference = 1000;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int lsum = 0;
        int rsum = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) lsum += A[j];
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) rsum += A[j];
        int difference = abs (lsum - rsum);
        if (difference < currentmindifference) currentmindifference = difference;
    }

    return currentmindifference;
}
```

Then, you can use `std::min`:

```
currentmindifference = std::min(difference, currentmindifference);
```

Then, you can use a single variable to handle the relative difference and call `abs` as you call `std::min` :

```
int solution(std::vector<int> &A) {
    int n = A.size();
    int currentmindifference = 1000;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int rel_diff = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)    rel_diff += A[j];
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) rel_diff -= A[j];
        currentmindifference = std::min(abs(rel_diff), currentmindifference);
    }

    return currentmindifference;
}
```

Now, to make your code more correct, you shouldn't assume `1000` will be the maximum : you can use `int minDifference = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();`.

*As I was about to handle the performance part, I realised that @Schism has already said what I wanted to say (and probably in a better way).*

Answer (score 4):

## Coding Style

#### Limit variable scope

It is best to limit the scope of your variables to the smallest scope possible. You aren't writing C89, so you don't need to declare variables at the top of the function.

#### Naming

Be sure to give descriptive names to variables and function parameters. `A` is not descriptive. Also, it's good to denote separation between words in names. `currentmindifference` is hard to read. You should pick either `camelCase` or `snake_case` for variable names and be consistent.

#### Use `const` where you can

If a variable is not supposed to be modified, it should be marked `const`. The compiler can then verify that the variable is never changed. Both `n` and `A` should be marked `const`.

## Algorithm

Inspired by Schism's linear-time solution, there are several opportunities to replace hand-written `for` loops with standard algorithms. These make the code easier to read and reason about. My implementation follows:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int solution(const std::vector<int>& values)
{
    if (values.empty()) {return std::numeric_limits<int>::max();}

    std::vector<int> partial, diffs;
    std::partial_sum(values.begin(), values.end(), std::back_inserter(partial));
    std::transform(partial.begin(), partial.end(), std::back_inserter(diffs), [&] (int x)
                   {
                       return std::abs(2 * x - partial.back());
                   });
    const auto min = std::min_element(diffs.begin(), diffs.end());
    return *min;
}
```

This consumes more memory than a hand-rolled loop because `diffs` needs to be filled with values. If memory is constrained, the calls to `std::transform()` and `std::min_element()` can be replaced with a hand-written loop.